# spring boot asynctask to process object array

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-async

I have a requirement in that I get a list of object from http request, I need to respond 202 and schedule my object array for paralelly processing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration 
{
    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}



@Service
public class AsyncService {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncService.class);

    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public void  processEmpoyess(List<Employees> employees) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        employees.forEach( item->{ log.info(item.name); try {
            log.info("Going to sleep " + item.name);
            Thread.sleep(10000); /* my business logic for each employee may take 5 to 10 seconds */
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } } );


        return  ;
    }

}


    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeelistfull", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postAllEmployees(@RequestBody Employees  employees) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
    {

        List<EmployeeAddress> listss = employees.getEmployeeList();
        service.processEmpoyess(listss);
    }
```

in my example I may get 1000 employees and I want to process 10 by 10 pararelly, business logic for each  employee may take 5 to 10 second.

With  my above code it is assigning to async task but async task is doing one by one.
So here do I need to create one more Async task and assign the employees ? or does async task has any other way to handle lists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending the list to the async method you have to split the list into chunks. In you case 10.

You could use Google Guava that has a partition function:

```
Lists.partition(java.util.List, int)
```

https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-

Comment: here I can split the list int to sublist,  say 100 sub list if I have 1000 but now I have to assign these 100 to async task, to do that I have to iterate 100 times, is there any way method where async task take this full and batch itslef .

Comment: No not out of the box.

Comment: okay, is there anyway to get the available pool details of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor before partitioning and  assigning to  async task ?

Comment: Yes just inject `TaskExecutor`